# Repeated ProgressBar activity for set of tasks in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-progressbar

I am new to android, don't have much experience to manage threads. I am working on an activity where I want to display progress bar for say 5 seconds and then repeat. During those 5 seconds, I will display some text for the user to work on the text. I want to repeat this for say N times.

Currently, I have the following code that works for 1 such progress. I tried looping it but it didn't help, as threads executed at same time. How can I repeat this for N number of times? Am I on the correct path in order to solve my the problem?

```
public class test extends Activity {

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private int progressStatus = 0;
    private TextView textView;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loop);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        progressBar.setScaleY(3f);
        // Start long running operation in a background thread

        for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
            Progress();

    }

    public void Progress(){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (progressStatus < 100) {
                    progressStatus += 1;
                    // Update the progress bar and display the
                    //current value in the text view
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                            textView.setText(progressStatus+"/"+progressBar.getMax());
                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        // Sleep for 200 milliseconds.
                        //Just to display the progress slowly
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: `During those 5 seconds, I will display some text for the user to work on the text.` ??? To work on a text displayed in a TextView? What should the user do with it?

Comment: Do not start five threads at once. Start the next thread when a thread is done. Or let the code in  run() run for five times in a loop.

Comment: What does it make sense that the user sees a progress five times?

Comment: I mean, I will test user's memory. I will keep the text for 5 seconds. And in the end I will test it in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I would recommend using the pattern you are following but here is the way to get the threads to run one after another rather than all at the same time:

```
public void progress(final int numberOfRuns) {
    if (numberOfRuns <= 0 ) {
        return;
    }
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (progressStatus < 100) {
                progressStatus += 1;
                // Update the progress bar and display the
                //current value in the text view
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                        textView.setText(progressStatus + "/" + progressBar.getMax());
                        // For the UI Changes. Eg update the loop number
                        myTextView.setText(Integer.toString(totalLoop));
                    }
                });
                try {
                    // Sleep for 200 milliseconds.
                    //Just to display the progress slowly
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            progressStatus = 0;
            totalLoop = totalLoop+1;
            progress(numberOfRuns - 1);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

then just call `progress(numberOfRuns)`, no need for any loops.

Comment: I am getting `Variable progressStatus is accessed from the inner class, needs to be declared final`. And making it final, we can change it in the at line `progressStatus +=1;

Comment: Aww shucks, good catch. I re-declared `progressStatus` in the function -_- I am correcting the code. Just note. I reset the value of progressStatus after each run of `progress()` so that the while loop will actually run from 0 - 100 each time through.

Comment: Finally I could do it. I just updated your answer with UI thread. Accept the edits so that I can accept the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Hey, I have another problem with this. After I get into this section, I can't escape from it. Even if I press back button, I get a this run in Background. Any better way to manage instead of just calling progress(10)?

Comment: Just saw this. I am about to hit the sack but I can take a look a this tomorrow afternoon. If you need faster feedback it may make sense to post another question, if you can wait I will play around with it tomorrow.

Comment: Well, you can combine setting the value of the two textViews into one runnable (as I have above). See if that has any impact, Ill play with it more when I get home.

Comment: I got it working by having a class variable and setting it to "true" "false" just before `onFinish()`, And same thing I checked in while `(progressStatus < 100 && loop==true)`. And since class variable was accessible by all threads. It worked :)